# Android not recognizing string resource

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, adt

In my android app, I have a string

```
<string name="action_upload">Upload Image</string>
```

in the strings file. Then in a menu file I have

navigation_screen.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="android.arin.NavigationScreen" >

    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_upload"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_upload"/>

    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_forward"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_forward"
    android:title="@string/action_forward"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

However when I try to run it, I get an error saying:

```
[2014-06-19 17:26:18 - ARIN] W/ResourceType( 9060): ResXMLTree_node size 0 is smaller than header size 0x100.
[2014-06-19 17:20:26 - ARIN] C:\Users\NAME\Documents\NAME\NAME\ARIN\res\menu\navigation_screen.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_upload').
```

I even tried a Project clean in eclipse, but still problem persists.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What build tools are you using?

Comment: How do I check that. The program is this http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This may seem like a weird answer, but did you save the xml file. Hit Ctrl-S and try it again.

If that doesn't work: Are the other strings you declared in the strings.xml file visible?

Comment: Yeah they are visible, If I remove that first item and run it, it works. There's something wrong with that item being there. Also I am using this menu file for an action bar if that matters. The second item is an icon for the bar, and the first item is for the menu.

Comment: Can you post the whole strings.xml file?

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it, I just re-imported the project into eclipse.